# Is there a faster way to get percent change?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with around 25000 records and 10 columns.  I am using code to determine the change to the previous value in the same column (NewVal) based on another column (y) with a percent change already in it.

```
x=c(1:25000)
y=rpois(25000,2)
z=data.frame(x,y)
z[1,'NewVal']=z[1,'x']
```

So I ran this:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(z)){z$NewVal[i]=z$NewVal[i-1]+(z$NewVal[i-1]*(z$y[i]/100))}
```

This takes considerably longer than I expected it to.  Granted I may be an impatient person - as a scathing letter drafted to me once said - but I am trying to escape the world of Excel (after I read http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/spreadsheet_addiction.html, which is causing me more problems as I have begun to mistrust data - that letter also mentioned my trust issues).

I would like to do this without using any of the functions from packages as I would like to know what the formula for creating the values is - or if you will, I am a demanding control freak according to that friendly missive.

I would also like to know how to get a moving average just like rollmean in caTools.  Either that or how do I figure out what their formula is?  I tried entering rollmean and I think it refers to another function (I am new to R).  This should probably be another question - but as that letter said, I don't ever make the right decisions in my life.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The secret in R is to vectorise.  In your example you can use `cumprod` to do the heavy lifting:

```
z$NewVal2 <- x[1] * cumprod(with(z, 1 +(c(0, y[-1]/100))))

all.equal(z$NewVal, z$NewVal2)
[1] TRUE

head(z, 10)
    x y   NewVal  NewVal2
1  25 4 25.00000 25.00000
2  24 3 25.75000 25.75000
3  23 0 25.75000 25.75000
4  22 1 26.00750 26.00750
5  21 3 26.78773 26.78773
6  20 2 27.32348 27.32348
7  19 2 27.86995 27.86995
8  18 3 28.70605 28.70605
9  17 4 29.85429 29.85429
10 16 2 30.45138 30.45138
```

On my machine, the loop takes just less than 3 minutes to run, while the `cumprod` statement is virtually instantaneous.

Comment: It works as long as `x=c(1:25000)` but if `x=c(25000:1)` I am getting a different result.

Comment: I hate to do this to you, but when `z$x[1]=0`, everything comes out 0.  In any case I am also checking out `cumprod` and `with` to see if I can come up with anything.

Comment: @thequerist  Yes, indeed. What do you expect the result to be in that case?  This is also true of the code you provide in your original question.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry; I misplaced the columns in the formula.  This works great!

Answer (score 6):

I got about a 800-fold improvement with `Reduce`:

```
    system.time(z[, "NewVal"] <-Reduce("*",  c(1, 1+z$y[-1]/100), accumulate=T) )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.139   0.008   0.148 

> head(z)
    x y NewVal
1   1 1  1.000
2   2 1  1.010
3   3 1  1.020
4   4 5  1.071
5   5 1  1.082
6   6 2  1.103
7   7 2  1.126
8   8 3  1.159
9   9 0  1.159
10 10 1  1.171
> system.time(for(i in 2:nrow(z)){z$NewVal[i]=z$NewVal[i-1]+
                                              (z$NewVal[i-1]*(z$y[i]/100))})
   user  system elapsed 
  37.29  106.38  143.16
```

Comment: Your `Reduce` function gives back only 24999 values, I think the starting `one (1)` should be `c`ombined to it before inserting to `z[, "Newval"]`. Anyway, I really like your solution (+1), could you please give some explanation why are you using `z$NewVal[-nrow(z)]` in the call insted of `z$NewVal[-1]`? I have to get a deeper look at `Reduce`...

Comment: @DWin This looks like a very interesting and promising approach. But I couldn't get it to work.  The code as supplied only works if the values of `z$NewValues` have already been calculated, i.e. when run on the original data with `z$NewValues <- 1` the results are meaningless.  Is there a missing line of code in your solution?

Comment: I had the recursion formula wrong. The `Reduce` approach can apply the same strategy that @Andrie's did. It is ten times slower than his however. (Still a big improvement over the for-loop.)

Comment: +1 Nice. So `Reduce` effectively replaces `cumprod` - this could be useful in those cases where a cumulative function isn't available.

Comment: That is its main role in "life". One just needs to get the iteration/recursion thought out properly, so thank you for providing that.

Comment: @DWin Thank you for posting this example.  I knew about `Reduce` and have used it but thought of it as essentially identical to `lapply`.  I didn't know about the `accumulate` argument - this puts an entirely different perspective on things.